# How to create a 2 dimensional vector with fixed length of column and dynamic length of row?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a 2 dimensional  vector of type char like this :

```
     std::vector< std::vector<char> > Input_Vector ;
```

I want the number of rows to be unknown and the number of columns to be fixed. Thus, each row of vector will contain 3 cells.

Comment: sounds like you want std::array?

Comment: `std::vector<std::array<char, FIXED_SIZE>>`?

Comment: @robthebloke  Actually I have never heard about this concept before. Is the deal with this concept is easy and clear like the deal with vectors  ?

Comment: Yup, it's basically a wrapper around a fixed sized C array. std::array<float, 10> will create a 10 element array

Comment: `std::array` has some quirks with initialization, watch out for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you know that the rows always have 3 cells each, you could use `std::array<char, 3>` as the element type. `std::array` can be indexed just like a regular vector, but internally it's just a c-style array. This means that there's no overhead with regard to using it, and it'll have better cache locality too when compared to a vector of vectors.

It can also be created with initializer-list like structure, too!

```
std::vector<std::array<char, 3>> vect;

vect.push_back({'a', 'b', 'c'}); // This works 

char c = vect[0][2]; // gets 'c'
```